# Windows 10 Open File dialog box. How can the folders not be displayed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, files-folders

In Windows 10 Standard Open File dialog box, I've set the View to display large icon thumbnails by date order.

Is there a way to prevent any sub folders from being displayed?

In Window's File Explorer there's an option under 'View' to 'GroupBy' date modified which pushes the folders to the bottom of the list. Is there a similar option in 'Open File' or perhaps another way?

Comment: There is a way to do this, but assuming you don't want this to be global, selective implementation could be tricky. Static location(s)? Need to sometimes use the dialog with subfolders shown for the folder in question? On my phone ATM, will post an answer with"proof-of-concept" when I get back to computer...

Answer (score 0):

You can search using the Open-Save dialog to display only files:

[image: Hide Folders]

- In the Search box, enter `NOT kind:folder`.
- Though there is a toggle at bottom-left, "Hide Folders", it restricts display to a *single* line of just *text*, thereby hiding *files and their icons*, as well... *not* generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

> In Window's File Explorer there's an option under 'View' to 'GroupBy' date modified which pushes the folders to the bottom of the list. Is there a similar option in 'Open File'

In the common dialogs, `Sort by` and `Group by` are found in the folder window background context menu:

[image]

> Is there a way to prevent any sub folders from being displayed?

Yes, with a little scripting magic. **Explorer** saves the view settings for both itself and the common dialogs under:

- `HKCU\Softare\Classes\LocalSettings\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`:

  [image]

The `FFlags` entry contains members of the [FolderFlags enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderflags) that control various aspects of the view, one of which is `FWF_NoSubfolders` (`0x80`), which suppresses the display of subfolders in the folder pane, but doesn't prohibit navigating to those subfolders via the Navigation Pane or typing in the Address bar.

It's quite easy to manipute for **Explorer** views, as this bit of **PowerShell** will toggle the display for all currently open **Explorer** windows. You can copy and paste ino a **PowerShell** console and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute; then <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>,<kbd>enter</kbd> to repeat and undo the change:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach{
    $_.Document.FolderFlags = ($_.Document.FolderFlags -bxor 0x80)
    $_.Refresh()
}
```

If you close the window with the flag set, it will be in effect the next time the folder is displayed, as it's part of the saved view settings.

But alas, dialogs are not so easy. We don't have access to the active dialog view the way we do with the shell com object, but if the `FFlags` entry of a *previously saved* view is modified, that will be used the next time the dialog is displayed. But every time a dialog is dismissed and its view settings are saved, `FFlags` is reset to 0x01, meaning the subfolders will be visible the next time the dialog is displayed.

So to hide subfolders in a dialog and have it persist, we deny ourselves permission to modify the registry key after we edit it. Unfortunately, this locks all other aspects of the saved view as well, so you want to make sure icon mode, column selection, etc. are to your liking before hiding subfolders. When we want to revert to normal display, we first remove the `Deny` permission and then restore the default value to `FFlags`.

So the following **PowerShell** code should be saved as a `.ps1` file in a directory of your choosing. Then, execute the script via dot-sourcing:

```
. <PathTofile>\<FileName>.ps1
```

This will create the necessary context menu entries in the regisry, and the option will be available via the background context menu or the FolderItem context menu.

```
#####################################################################################################################################################
#   
#   Context menu syntax:
#    - Directory backgrund:
#   powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File <pathToThisScript> "%V" Show|Hide Background
#    - Directory (selected item):
#   powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File <pathToThisScript> "%V" Show|Hide
#
#####################################################################################################################################################

#############################################################################################
#
#   Pinvoke and wrapper function for SHGetNameFromIDList(). This facilitates traversing
#    the BagMRU index to deterimine the property bag of the view for the target directory.
#
#   Wrapper syntax: [string] GetFolderName(Byte[] IDL)
#
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class API
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
    static extern int SHGetNameFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, uint sigdnName, out StringBuilder ppszName);

    static public string GetFolderName(Byte[] IDL) {
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(IDL, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr PIDL          = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        StringBuilder name   = new StringBuilder(2048);
        int result           = SHGetNameFromIDList(PIDL, 0x0, out name);
        pinnedArray.Free();
        return name.ToString();
    }
}
"@ # End Add-Type

#############################################################################################
#
#   Get-NSPath: Determine the fully-qualified path within the shell namespace. In essence,
#       a human-readable IDL that generally mirrors the Address bar text.
#
Function Get-NSPath ($comFolder) {
    If ($comFolder.ParentFolder)        {
        $ParentPath     = Get-NSPath $comFolder.ParentFolder
        ###   Return from subfolder recursion:
        '{0}\{1}'       -f $ParentPath , $comFolder.Title
    } Else {
        ###   Return from Desktop:
        $comFolder.Title
    }
}
#############################################################################################
#   
#   Get-BagNumber: With the NSPath, locate the MRU node for the target folder and return
#   the correspoinding NodeSLot (Bag #).
#
Function Get-BagNumber ($NSPath) {
    $BagMRU            = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'
    $MRUNode           = Get-Item $BagMRU 
    [Byte[]]$parentIDL = [Byte[]]@()

    If ($NSPath -match '\\') {
        $NSPath        = $NSPath -replace '^Desktop\\'
        $FolderNames   = $NSPath.Split('\')
        ForEach ($folderName in @($FolderNames)) {
            $node          = @($MRUNode.GetValueNames() -match '\d+').Where{[API]::GetFolderName($parentIDL + $MRUNode.GetValue($_)) -eq $folderName}[0]
            $idl           = $MRUNode.GetValue($node)
            $MRUNode       = $MRUNode.OpenSubKey($node)
            $parentIDL     = $parentIDL + [Byte[]]($idl[0..($idl.Length-3)])
        }
    }
    ###   Return value:
    $MRUNode.GetValue('NodeSlot')
}
#############################################################################################
#   
#   Set-NoSubfolders: Sets or clears the FWF_NoSubfolders flag and modifies permissions
#    for any ComDLg subkeys under the specified bag.
#   
Function Set-NoSubfolders ([String]$BagNum , [Bool]$NoSubfolders) {
    $Bags       = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
    $dlgCount   = 0
    Get-ChildItem "$Bags\$BagNum" -Recurse | where Name -match 'ComDlg\w*\\' | ForEach {
        $dlgCount += 1
        Write-Verbose   ('{3,-15}: {0}\{1}\{2}' -f ($_.PSParentPath.Split('\')[9..11] + 'Dialog view'))
        $splat = @{
            'Name'    = 'FFlags'
            'Value'   = $(If ($NoSubfolders) {0x81} Else {0x01})
        }
        If ($NoSubfolders) {   ###   Set the flag and then deny SetValue permission
            Lock-KeyValues $_.PSParentPath $false
            $_ | Set-ItemProperty @splat
            Lock-KeyValues $_.PSParentPath $true
            Write-Verbose "`tFWF_NoSubfolders set."
        } Else {   ###   Remove "deny SetValue" permission and clear flag 
            Lock-KeyValues $_.PSParentPath $false
            $_ | Set-ItemProperty @splat
            Write-Verbose "`tFWF_NoSubfolders cleared."
        }
    }
    If ($dlgCount -eq 0) {
        Write-Warning "`n`tNo dialog views saved yet for this folder.`n"
    }
}
#############################################################################################
#   
#   Function Lock-KeyValues: Adds or removes a "Deny SetValue" rule to the ACL of the modified key.
#   The rule is added when subfolders are hidden to prevent the FFlags value from being reset to the default.
#   The rule is removed when the NoSubfolders flag is cleared.
#   All aspects of the view are frozen when the rule is added, so best to customize other aspects of the dialog view before hiding subfolders.
#   
Function Lock-KeyValues ($keyPath , [Bool]$lock) {
    $DenySetValue   = [Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule]::new("$env:UserDomain\$env:UserName","SetValue","ContainerInherit","InheritOnly","Deny")
    $kacl           = Get-Acl $keyPath
    If ($Lock) {
        $kacl.AddAccessRule($DenySetValue) | out-null
    }
    Else {
        $kacl.RemoveAccessRule($DenySetValue) | out-null
    }
    Set-Acl -Path $keyPath -AclObject $kAcl 
}
#############################################################################################
###   Main
#############################################################################################

If ($Args) {   ###   Invoked from context menu
    $VerbosePreference   = 'continue'
    $folderPath          = $Args[0]
    $Shell               = New-Object -com shell.application
    If ($Args.Count -eq 3) {
        Write-Verbose      'Invoked from folder background...'
        Write-Verbose      ('{1,-15}:"{0}"' -f $folderPath, 'Folder path')
        $win             = @($shell.windows() | where $folderPath -eq $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path)[0]
        $NSPath          = Get-NSPath $win.Document.Folder
    } Else {
        Write-Verbose      'Invoked from FolderItem...'
        Write-Verbose      ('{1,-15}:"{0}"' -f $folderPath, 'folderPath')
        $win             = @($shell.windows() | where $folderPath -eq $_.Document.FocusedItem.Path)[0]
        $NSPath          = '{0}\{1}' -f (Get-NSPath $win.Document.Folder) , (Split-Path $folderPath -Leaf)
    }
    Write-Verbose          ('{1,-15}: "{0}"' -f $win.Document.Folder.Title , 'Window title')
    Write-Verbose          ('{1,-15}: "{0}"' -f $NSPath , 'Namespace path')
    $TargetBag           = Get-BagNumber $NSPath
    Write-Verbose          ('{1,-15}: {0}' -f $TargetBag , 'Target bag')
    If ($TargetBag) {
        Write-Verbose      ('{1,-15}: "{0}"' -f $Args[1], 'Action')
        Set-NoSubfolders $TargetBag ($Args[1] -eq 'Hide')
    }
    Read-Host "`n`tDone. Press <enter> to close this window.`n"

###   End context menu invocation

} Else {   ###   Invoked with no arguments triggers context menu item creation
    If ($PSCommandPath) {
        $MenuText       = '&Hide/show subfolders in dialogs'
        $keyRoot        = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory'
        $HideShow       = @{
                    '1' = 'Hide'
                    '2' = 'Show'
        }
        $menuItemProps      = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'MuiVerb'       =   $MenuText
            'SubCommands'   =   ''
        }
        ###   Registry key/entry creation loop
        'Background' , $null | ForEach {$_} -pv pvISBackground | ForEach {
            (mkdir (Join-Path $keyRoot $_ | Join-Path -CHildPath 'shell\HSDS') -Force).PSPath
        } -pv pvMenuItem | ForEach {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $_ -InputObject $menuItemProps
            '1' , '2' | ForEach {
                $subCmdPath     = (mkdir (Join-Path $pvMenuItem "Shell\$_") -Force).PSPath
                Set-ItemProperty -Path $subCmdPath -Name MuiVerb -Value "&$($HideShow[$_])"
                $splat              = @{
                        'Path'      = $subCmdPath
                        'Name'      = 'Command'
                        'Value'     = ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "{0}" "%V" {1} {2}' -f $PSCommandPath , $HideShow[$_] , $pvISBackground).Trim()
                        'Type'      = 'ExpandString'
                }
                New-Item @splat -Force
            }
        }
        Write-HOst 'Context menu entries created.'
    } Else {
        Write-Warning "`n`tSave this script to a .ps1 file and then invoke via dot-sourcing to install as context menu item.`n"
    }
}
#############################################################################################
```